How to Detect Missing Closing Braces ">" for HTML tag in Python Code
I cant seem to figure out how to get my program to detect missing >'s from HTML files, everything I've tried returns "Valid HTML". The program properly detects missing <'s and /'s
I am not allowed to use any imports for this program
My Code:
filePath = input("Enter the file path of your HTML file: ")

with open(filePath, "r") as file:
    content = file.read()

tagList = []
mismatch = False

for i in range(len(content)):

    if content[i] == "<":

        if content[i : i + 2] != "</":

            endOfTag = content.find(">", i + 1)

            if endOfTag != -1:
                tag = content[i : endOfTag + 1]
                tagType = tag[1 : -1].split()[0]

                tagList.append(tagType)
        else:
         closingTagType = content[i + 2 : content.find(">", i + 1)]
         if tagList and tagList[-1] == closingTagType:
         tagList.pop()
         else:
             print("Invalid HTML, mismatched opening and closing braces")
             mismatch = True
             break

if len(tagList) == 0:
    print("Valid HTML")
elif not mismatch:
    print("Invalid HTML, mismatched opening and closing braces")


What is .find finding in the first line of the for loop?

End of tag shouldn't have an index of -1, even if it is the last element. Try using len instead.

Detecting invalid HTML code can be challenging because HTML has a loose syntax. Whatever logic you right may help to some extent, But it might not handle all edge cases. I would suggest you to look for other validators instead of coding the all edge cases. In your case what if body have < or > in text? ...It will be a false alarm..

Another thing you also need to take care of is the unpaired tags in HTML, some tags for example, <meta>, <link> etc do not have their corresponding closing tag and if they are involved in the html file (which they will be since they are very common and important tags), your script will still return "Invalid HTML" even if everything is well written in the html file. You could try to make a list of exceptional tags and check if the current selected tag belongs to that list.

Also, it's the best practice to make your output more descriptive. For example, if there is a mismatched tag, then only return "Invalid HTML: Mismatched tag", and same for missing closing braces. Also, you could include the tag in which this problem has occured.

Please preserve the question as it is so that it may still be useful for later readers. As for Turnitin, I'm sure that its users are wise enough not to blindly trust it anyway.

Made some edits to make the question better fit the provided edits. Hopefully, people find what they are looking for!

All you need to do is count the number of left- and right-braces. You also have to account for braces that might occur within quotes (e.g., in a title). You also need to account for the interchangeability of quotes mark - i.e., both " and ' may be used providing they are matched.
Here's a simplistic approach to validating HTML in terms of its brace matching.
with open("/Users/SIGHUP/foo.html") as file:
    brace_count = 0
    start_quote = None
    for c in file.read():
        if c in "\"'":
            if start_quote is None:
                start_quote = c
            elif c == start_quote:
                start_quote = None
        if not start_quote:
            if c == "<":
                brace_count += 1
            elif c == ">":
                brace_count -= 1
    if brace_count == 0:
        print("OK")
    else:
        print("Invalid HTML - mismatched braces")


Awesome! I'm going to modify my code a bit with this logic. Thanks!
